# how to accept both null or string field in nestjs

Tags: javascript, class, nestjs, nest, prisma

```
import {
  IsDefined,
  IsString,
  IsEmail,
  IsOptional,
  Allow,
} from 'class-validator';
import { BaseCommand } from 'shared/commands/BaseCommand';

export class RegisterCommand extends BaseCommand {

  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Allow()
  @IsString()
  password?: string | null;
}
```

I have to accept either if user enter a password or also if I want don't want to allow them to enter password (because I want to implement google login and need to store email and name in db) then how can I achieve this?

currenyly I am getting error:

```
 response: {
    statusCode: 400,
    message: [
      'password should not be null or undefined',
      'password must be a string'
    ],
    error: 'Bad Request'
  },
```

Comment: The `password` field must not be included in the request at all for `@isOptional()` to work. If you are sending `"password": null"`, it is considered as a present field with a `null` value and `@isString()` will fail. Do you need to allow explicit `null` values? I can share how you can create a custom validator if so.

Comment: @ErhanÇapar please share custom validator. 
on payload I will not send password.

Comment: U can use only @IsString() and @IsOptional() decorators (without @IsAllow()) and it should work, no need for any custom validators

Answer (score 1):

If you need to allow explicit `null` values, you will have to create a custom validator. Here's how to do it with a custom validator:

```
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface, ValidationArguments, registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'IsStringOrNull', async: false })
export class IsStringOrNullConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        return typeof value === 'string' || value === null; // for async validations you must return a Promise<boolean> here
    }

    defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
        return 'Text ($value) must be a string or null!';
    }
}

export function IsStringOrNull(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: 'IsStringOrNull',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: IsStringOrNullConstraint,
        });
    };
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
@IsDefined()
@IsStringOrNull()
password?: string | null;
```

See if this will solve your issue.

Comment: above code not worked getting same issue

Comment: after this do I need to again fire prisma generate command?

Comment: `prisma generate` command is used to access your database, while in this case the problem seems to be related to NestJS validation, so no. Can you share your error message after the custom validation?

Comment: Yeah I am also not sure what casing the issue. If i pass password in payload its working fine